# Why can't I update a p:graphicImage twice after upload a file with p:uploadFile

Tags: primefaces

I have been trying to upload an image with a p:uploadFile and it work fine at first time, but after the first uploaded file it not update the p:graphicImage, but if I reload the page the value of the graphicImage is fine and the image is showed. So, I think that is a problem with the primefaces uploadFile component, but I not sure.

My xhtml is this:

```
<h:form id="formNuevo" size="150%"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <h:outputLabel value="Diseño Neumatico: *" />
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{serviciosVentanaDiseno.manejarUploadedFile}" mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="9000000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" update="mensajes graficImage"/>                          

<p:graphicImage id="graficImage" styleClass="disenoNeumatico" value="#{serviciosVentanaDiseno.streamedContentImagen}" ajax="true"/>



 </h:form>
```

and my bean is a @SessionScoped bean, it's here:

```
public void manejarUploadedFile(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = (UploadedFile)event.getFile();
    try {                    
        diseno.setImagen(uploadedFile.getContents());
        streamedContentImagen = new DefaultStreamedContent(new    ByteArrayInputStream(diseno.getImagen()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log error
    }
}

public StreamedContent getStreamedContentImagen() {
    return streamedContentImagen;
}

public void setStreamedContentImagen(StreamedContent streamedContentImagen) {
    this.streamedContentImagen = streamedContentImagen;
}
```

Comment: It's just a guess but the browser might be caching the image. Try setting the cache attribute of the graphicImage component to false: <p:graphicImage cache="false"

Comment: I'm gonna submit my comment as an answer so it might solve issues for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the cache attribute of the graphicImage component to false: 
`<p:graphicImage cache="false"`

Answer (score 0):

change scope `@SessionScoped` then `<p:graphicImage cache="false">`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?